# How to insert a table name into data that is sent to front-end using axios?

Tags: php, axios, reactphp

I am fetching a data according to the table name, but I also need to send the table name to the front end along with the data. I have this code.

```
$sql_fetchItems = "select * from `$cat`";
        $result_fetchItems = mysqli_query($connection, $sql_fetchItems);
        for ($j; $j < mysqli_num_rows($result_fetchItems); $j++) {
            echo ($j > 0 ? ',' : '') . json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result_fetchItems));
        }
```

where the objects will be encoded and sent to the front-end. if I add ",{$cat}" within the `for` statement, it will become another object of course. But is there a way to send the table name along with the object? Like in the JS console, it should receive `{"name": "1", "category", "something", "something": "something"}`?

Comment: Why are you `echo`ing inside a loop?

Comment: Sending table names from front-end  looks bad to me. It's insecure and not the right way to achieve things.

Comment: Of course, to send data to the react front-end @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: I am not showing the table name or doing anything with it, it will just be resent to the back-end in to serve another function. I am doing an e-commerce and since I have an "All" option in the `select tag` where all of the items will be shown, i cannot get the right category name. @vivek_23

Comment: @KyiZin Well typically, you would use a PHP variable to add the results in the loop and echo that variable. You can add the table name easily to that variable using `$cat`

Comment: @KyiZin What is someone inspects the page and edits the value as `table_name; drop table tablename;`. You need to use bind params etc to prevent SQL injection, but even then why expose the table name to people? Also, a select dropdown will have values belonging to a table rather than deciding table names to fetch from.

Comment: @vivek_23 it is just my final school project, so I wouldn't so care about security issues right now although i do know exposing data is not a good practice

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I do get your idea but, since `json_encode(mysqli_fetch_object($result_fetchItems))` returns a string and ends in }], is there a way to append that string ?

Comment: You don't need `json_encode` until you are ready to return data using `echo`

Comment: Oh, I just got it, thank you mr. @AnuragSrivastava